# How do I convert this function into a class component so that I can use render to call the return?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, render

The goal of the below code is to import the data from the move object into the firestore database under the user's id. Everything works except for when I hit the liked button, the display doesn't update. I know from console.log statements that when the like button is pushed, a different movie is correctly selected from the array (using the random index variable), but the actual title and coverart isn't being updated as the reference movie changes.

How can I change the code so that the return statement will execute again and update the display once I push the liked button?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/firestore';

function RateMovies() {

    const popularMoviesRef = firebase.database().ref("/popular_movies");
    const [popularMovies, setPopularMovies] = React.useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        
        popularMoviesRef.once("value", function(snapshot){

            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                var key = childSnapshot.key;
                var data = childSnapshot.val();

                setPopularMovies(currMovies => [...currMovies, { 
                    key: key, 
                    movieTitle: data.movie_title, 
                    moviePoster: data.movie_poster, 
                    movieYear: data.movie_year,
                    movieGenre: data.movie_genre, 
                    movieRating: data.imdb_rating
                }])
            });
        });
    }, []);

    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 + 1));
    var movie = popularMovies[index];

    const auth = firebase.auth();
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var user_id = auth.currentUser.uid;

    function likedMovie() {

        db.collection('users').doc(user_id).update({
            "Rated.liked": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                key: movie.key, 
                movieTitle: movie.movieTitle, 
                moviePoster: movie.moviePoster, 
                movieYear: movie.movieYear,
                movieGenre: movie.movieGenre, 
                movieRating: movie.movieRating,
             }),
        })
        .then(function(){
            console.log("Successfully updated!");
        });

        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 + 1));
        movie = popularMovies[index];
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <p>Rate Movies Here</p>
            <div> {movie?.movieTitle} </div>
            <div> {movie?.movieYear} </div>
            <br/>
            <button onClick={likedMovie}> Like</button>
            <button> Disike</button>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <img class="rate-image" src = {`${movie?.moviePoster}`} />
            
        </div>
    )
  
  } 

  export default RateMovies;
```

Comment: You  need to call `setPopularMovies` again after updating and the render will trigger itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution but a workaraound

```
 const [render, setRender] = React.useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        
        popularMoviesRef.once("value", function(snapshot){

            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
                var key = childSnapshot.key;
                var data = childSnapshot.val();

                setPopularMovies(currMovies => [...currMovies, { 
                    key: key, 
                    movieTitle: data.movie_title, 
                    moviePoster: data.movie_poster, 
                    movieYear: data.movie_year,
                    movieGenre: data.movie_genre, 
                    movieRating: data.imdb_rating
                }])
            });
        });
    }, [render]);

    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 + 1));
    var movie = popularMovies[index];

    const auth = firebase.auth();
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var user_id = auth.currentUser.uid;

    function likedMovie() {

        db.collection('users').doc(user_id).update({
            "Rated.liked": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
                key: movie.key, 
                movieTitle: movie.movieTitle, 
                moviePoster: movie.moviePoster, 
                movieYear: movie.movieYear,
                movieGenre: movie.movieGenre, 
                movieRating: movie.movieRating,
             }),
        })
        .then(function(){
            console.log("Successfully updated!");
            setRender(render++)
        });

        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 + 1));
        movie = popularMovies[index];
    }
```

Comment: This is works, but it is a tad slow. Would you happen to know why the entire function runs 1000 times (the size of the popularMoviesRef database) every time it renders?

Comment: @Kris are you talking about re-rendering or firebase query payload? please rectify your question

Comment: I'm not sure, but if I put a console.log on the line above the useEffect() it executes 1000 times when the page loads and every time the button is pushed. 

Additionally, I just realized that the button has to be pushed twice for the display to update. So, if the array was initially at index 1, then pushing the button updates it to index 2, but the display doesn't change. Then when I push the button again, it updates to index 3 and the display changes to display the information of index 3 (but I never see the information of index 2 displayed).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use function component just get rid of render method and leave it like this:

```
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Rate Movies Here</p>
            <button onClick={likedMovie}> Like</button>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: I'm trying to go in the opposite direction. It previously was a function but I want to be able to use render

Comment: Why is that? You can do everything with function components it's recommended way

Comment: Ok then how do I execute the return statement after the button is pushed so that the display updates without using render?

Comment: please add more context to your question so we can help.

Comment: @abhipatil I've updated my question to completely reflect what my issue is